# How to add dynamic width values to a class with pseudo selector?

Tags: css

I have the following element with a variable number of sections within:

```
<div class="accordion horizontal">
<section id="A">...</section>
<section id="B">...</section>
...
</div>
```

I need to set the value for the width attribute according to the number of sections.

```
/* CSS */
    .horizontal :target {
    width: ? %;
    }
```

What is the best practice to add to this element dynamic width(%) values?

Comment: Why not just `width: xx%`?

Comment: question is unclear...

Comment: maybe explain the problem you are having as the question doesn't make sense. why is height:100% not working for you?

Comment: the `:target` element *is* the `.horizontal` element, or it's contained *within* the `.horizontal` element? Because your question seems to say the former, your CSS shows the latter. And you're styling the `height` not the `width`. You need to clearly explain, to a group of people that have no idea what you're doing, or why, what it is that you want to do. And, ideally, *why*.

Comment: Its a <div> with class .horizontal. The :target element is for the elements within (its children <section id="A">..</section>,<section id="B">..</section> ).  The width value will depend on the number of children. I hope its a little bit more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be space between element selector and `:target` pseudo selector:

```
.horizontal:target { /*not .horizontal :target */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;/*question is unclear though of this use*/
}
```

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal the width should be dynamic and not 100%. The % value will depend on the number of sections.